# DateTime.Ticks for nullable datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

In my app, article.DatePublished is a nullable DateTime field. Now I have this following code:

```
      list.Add(article.DatePublished.Ticks);
```

Here I am getting a compile error as Ticks property does not work with nullable DateTimes.

One way of handling this is:

```
if (article.DatePublished != null)
      list.Add(((DateTime)article.DatePublished).Ticks);
```

This works, but is this an elegant solution? Or can we make it "better"?

Thanks,

Vivek

Comment: Don't know how `elegant` this is but you could use `yourDate.HasValue` :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to get at the `.Value` property of the `DateTime?`.

```
if (nullableDate != null) // or if (nullableDate.HasValue)
    ticks = nullableDate.Value.Ticks;
```

You could otherwise use `nullableDate.GetValueOrDefault().Ticks`, which would normalize a null date into the default value of `DateTime`, which is `DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: perfect, the GetValueOrDefault().Ticks made my day :)

Answer (score 3):

As Icarus mentioned, I'd use:

```
if (article.DatePublished != null)
{
    list.Add(article.DatePublished.Value.Ticks);
}
```

Or even:

```
if (article.DatePublished.HasValue)
{
    list.Add(article.DatePublished.Value.Ticks);
}
```

Depending on what you're trying to do, it could be that LINQ will give you simpler code:

```
var list = articles.Select(article => article.DatePublished)
                   .Where(date => date != null)
                   .Select(date => date.Ticks)
                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (article.DatePublished.HasValue)
{
      list.Add(article.DatePublished.Value.Ticks);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to add a value, including a default if DatePublished is null, you could do something like

```
var date = article.DatePublished ?? new DateTime(whatever);
list.Add(date.Ticks);
```